# Perl substitute to print everything not matched with regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to print everything remaining that is not matched from my regex. I know the regex is good but not sure I understand the syntax correctly to execute it right. The print that I get is not at all what I have using regex101. Any ideas would be helpful. Trying to print the remaining context not matched and eventually out to another file but want to make sure I also understand the comment. Here is what I have...

```
perl -ne "print s/((0\.0\.0\.0)|(127\.0\.0\.1)|(\|\|)|(#.*)|(\^)|(\h))/m/gi;" a.txt
```

Comment: So here you are trying to match either `0.0.0.0`, `127.0.0.1`, `||`, `#.*` (any # sign and everything after it) , `^`, `\h` (horizontal whitespace). And you want to replace it with an `m`. You want to do this multiple times and case insensitive (despite not actually using any letters). Are you certain this regex is working? This would print a number for each line, the number of times the regex matches. The file itself and the changes to the lines would be unused. Perhaps you meant to use the `-p` switch instead of `-n`. (and remove `print`).

Comment: You can remove all the parentheses from this regex, since they are all unused and redundant. You can also remove `/i` as reduntant.

Comment: If you have some test cases and expected output, that would help.

Comment: the regex portion in para's was working on regex101. the rest I just picked up from searches so im sure that is wrong. I want to match, 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, ||, #.*(comments at the end of lines), ^, and horizontal whitespace and replace it with nothing and have the command print the remaining that is not matched.

Comment: @TLP 'perl -pe "s/((0\.0\.0\.0)|(127\.0\.0\.1)|(\|\|)|(#.*)|(\^)|(\h))//gi;" a.txt' seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works.

```
perl -pe "s/((0\.0\.0\.0)|(127\.0\.0\.1)|(\|\|)|(#.*)|(\^)|(\h))//gi;" a.txt
```

Comment: The `-n` used in the question iterates over lines of input, applying given code to each; the code `print`s the return of the `s///` operator -- the number of substitutions made!  Not what you want.  Now, this `-p` used in this answer also applies code to each line of input, but then it also prints that processed line of input.  So it prints `$_` _after_ the regex did its thing to it.  Since in the regex you remove all matches this ends up printing what wasn't matched.  That's how it "works"

Comment: I told you that the parentheses and the `/i` modifier are redundant. The i modifier makes it so that letters match regardless of case (e.g. `/a/i` matches both `a` and `A`). The parentheses capture text, so that you can reuse it in the LHS, with `$1`, `$2` etc. None of that is used in your regex.